# asp.net multidimensional array matrix to jagged

Tags: asp.net, arrays, matrix

```
double[,] sourceMatrix = source.ToMatrix(out columnNames);
double[][] inputs = sourceMatrix.GetColumns(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13).ToJagged();
```

basically, double [,] is a source matrix taken from Excel. In this examples, we hardcode taking columns 1 through 13 when converting to a two dimensional array. However, what if the number of the columns to be used was a variable (it could be 13, 20, anything) - how can I achieve the same conversion without hardcoding the index of each column to be used and instead just specify the range or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

```
double[][] inputs = sourceMatrix.GetColumns(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13 }).ToJagged();
```

where the parameter can be generated dynamically